# How to restart a modded Minecraft server every 24 hours?

Tags: command-line, server, minecraft

I made a `.SH` file that looks like this:

Letting people know that the server is going to restart:

```
tmux send-keys -t VHS "/say §cServer restarting in §l30 minutes. §rPlease get ready to log off." Enter

# Wait for 1770 seconds (29 minutes and 30 seconds)
sleep 1770s
```

Send messages to the server indicating the restart countdown:

```
tmux send-keys -t VHS "/say §cServer is restarting in §l30 seconds! §rthe restart will take aproximately 5 minutes!" Enter
sleep 20s

tmux send-keys -t VHS "/say §cServer is restarting in §l10 seconds!" Enter
sleep 5s

tmux send-keys -t VHS "/say §cServer is restarting in §l5 seconds!" Enter
sleep 1s

tmux send-keys -t VHS "/say §cServer is restarting in §l4 seconds!" Enter
sleep 1s

tmux send-keys -t VHS "/say §cServer is restarting in §l3 seconds!" Enter
sleep 1s

tmux send-keys -t VHS "/say §cServer is restarting in §l2 seconds!" Enter
sleep 1s

tmux send-keys -t VHS "/say §cServer is restarting in §l1 second!" Enter
sleep 1s
```

Stop the Minecraft server:

```
tmux send-keys -t VHS "/stop" Enter
sleep 300s
```

Restart the server using the `run.sh` script:

```
tmux send-keys -t VHS "./run.sh" Enter
```

And the line of code I have made for the crontab looks like this:

```
0 21 * * * /VHServer/restart.sh
```

The `.sh` file seems to run everything but the `/stop` command and possibly the `./run.sh` I have set up for the server, can I please get an explanation why?

Comment: `./run.sh` is a path relative to your current working directory that might not be the same working directory for `cron` ... So what seems obvious to you isn't necessarily obvious to `cron`  ... You need to provide the full path instead like for example `/home/username/run.sh`.

Comment: Thankyou, so if I understand this correctly I need to add another line to the Cron job that executes the ru.sh file directly rather than through the restart.sh. if that's the case I will need to edit the run.sh file to open up a tmux session or send that command into the tmux session correct?

Comment: You're welcome ... No, just change `tmux send-keys -t VHS "./run.sh" Enter` to something like `tmux send-keys -t VHS "/home/username/run.sh" Enter` i.e. the full path to the `run.sh` script inside `/VHServer/restart.sh`

Comment: all seems to work now! thanks!